# Why is Joe’s body perfectly fine when he returns to Earth?

Tags: plot-explanation, soul

In the Pixar movie *Soul* the main character accidentally falls into a manhole. He hits the ground so hard that he actually dies. However, when he comes back to Earth and gets into the cat’s body, his actual human body is perfectly fine.

This raises the question of how his body has no severe damage from a fall so severe he died?

Comment: This is Disney… do we show smashed-up, bleeding bodies? Do we show entire populations of dead people as anything other than smiling, happy skeletons? Do we give the Little Mermaid nipples? The answer to all these is a resounding **No**.

Comment: He didn't die, he wakes up in a hospital room when he returns to Earth, so presumably he was in some kind of near-death coma.

Comment: He didn't fall of a cliff, just down a manhole, presumably some head trauma, that should be lethal, but (as long as he didn't get to proper afterlife) wasn't.